# Modal timer progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timer

I have a modal for when a button is clicked. The modal popups and closes when the timer is up, currently 5 seconds. However, I would like to create a progress bar which shows the timer going down, no numbers just a bar that moves.

Here is what I already have: https://jsfiddle.net/cde2cup0/. YOU MUST CLICK THE BUTTON 'ADMINISTRATION' for the modal.

And here's what I want to achieve. I know my Photoshop skills aren't on point, was rushing:

[image: Example]

The white bar at the bottom is the progress bar.

I did try this but wasn't suitable for what I needed so didn't work.

```
var start = new Date();
var maxTime = 835000;

var timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime/100);

animateUpdate();

function updateProgress(percentage) {
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').text(percentage + "%");
}

function animateUpdate() {
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
    var perc = Math.round((timeDiff/maxTime)*100);
      if (perc <= 100) {
       updateProgress(perc);
       setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);
      }
}
```

Reference: [jQuery progress timer bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151758/jquery-progress-timer-bar)

Comment: Use either the <meter> or <progress> html elements

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if correctly understood your question, but hope that helps:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cde2cup0/2/

```
var progressBar = document.getElementById('myProgressBar');
function setAnimation(timeInSeconds, callbackFunction) {
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (count == timeInSeconds) {
            callbackFunction();
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        progressBar.style.width = (100 * count / timeInSeconds) + '%';
        count++;
    }, 1000);
};
```